# Different session id between php pages

Tags: php, ajax

I want to share a variable between pages through the `$SESSION`  variable. In file1.php I have

```
<?php session_start();
   require_once('connect.php');
   global $gb;
   $_SESSION['myvar'] = "somestring";
   // Some other code
?>
```

And in my second fille2.php I have

```
<?php session_start();
   require_once('connect.php');
   $myvar = $_SESSION['myvar'];
?>
```

and `$myvar` is empty. I first make an ajax call to file1.php and then file2.php. I've tried echoing `session_id()` and it's different. What's wrong here?

**Edit:** I am calling my server side PHP script from localhost and using Chrome with the CORS plugin enabled if that matters

Comment: Are both files on the same server with the exact same domain?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yes they are.

Comment: I don't think you need `session_start();` in `file2.php` again

Comment: @andre3wap Ohhhhh yes you do

Comment: Are these 2 files being run in the same session??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not sure what you mean. I first make a call from JS to file1.php, on success on that call I make second call to file2.php

Comment: So yes they probably are in the same session

Comment: Ok so what makes you think the session has lost this value. Maybe it has not and there is just something else wrong with the code in `file2.php` Show more code, how do you attempt to make use of the session value

Comment: @RiggsFolly the session_id() should not be different if they share the same session right? In file1.php I basically just echo intval(true); back to client

Comment: Do you have any blank lines above the `<?php` in file2

Comment: Have you checked the php error log for any clues

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean, but If I have understood properly, both files are being called by an js script using AJAX. If you could include the js code where the call is being done, that would be really helpful. Anyway, I'm pretty sure that the second file is being downloaded before the first one. Something you can do to workaround  this is to abstract both `session_start()` and the `$_SESSION['myvar']` variable declaration in another file or in the top of your current file, for example in a file called 'session_init.php' It should look like this :

session_init.php :

```
<?php

//init session and session variable
session_start(); 
/* $_SESSION['myvar'] = 'value'; */
```

your current file (the file where you are making the AJAX  request) :

```
<?php

//include this folder on the top of the page where the ajax petition is made
require_once('session_init.php');
$_SESSION['myvar'] = 'Some Value';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

  //js code to make ajax petitio to file 1

  $.ajax({

    //parameters and other stuff

    success : function(resp){

          //js code to make ajax petition to file 2
          $.ajax({

             //parameters and other stuff
          });
      }
  })
 </script>
```

Now `$_SESSION['myvar']` should be accessible in both files as long as you declare `session_start()` at the top of each file. Remember that is not a good practice to nest AJAX petitions. Also you can take a different approach to send the data trough the files, for example, sending the value of 'myvar' as a parameter on the AJAX request.

Comment: I don't think OP would want to statically set $_SESSION['myvar'] to 'value' at the beginning of every file. That kind of defeats the purpose of what he's doing. Manipulating and fetching the content of the session should be done on a per file basis; session start is fine to be in that file though. I've made a suggested edit to your post (Which hopefully will be accepted), that corrects this issue.

Comment: Yes you are right. I did not notice that he was setting the value of $_SESSION['myvar`] on the file1, so thank you for editing. Anyway, you can set a default value on 'session_init.php' and then change it whenever you want.

Comment: The problem would be on the second page the original value would be overwritten with the default value.

Comment: Yes , I wanted to edit my comment as soon as I added it but I couldn't. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not calling `session_start()` from the file making the AJAX calls, which will result in two different sessions. That, or you're regenerating the session ID somewhere within `connect.php`

If that doesn't help you resolve your issue, then please provide all relevant code so I can attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: Hey! How do you mean that I need to call session_start() from the file making AJAX calls. Do I need to call it from my JS file?

Comment: @novalain from the PHP file that is executing the AJAX, not the JS file.